# Android Development: How to create a network login via https

Tags: java, android, https, port

I have searched the web and to no avail have I found the answer to my problem.

I require my android app to connect to my web server.

example `https://SERVER-ADDRESS:PORT/`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
String url = "https://SERVER-ADDRESS:PORT/site/login?username=" + user + "&password=" + password;
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000 * 60 * 2);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

        //prepare the HTTP GET call 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        //get the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            //get the response content as a string
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //consume the entity
            entity.consumeContent();

            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
           }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! How can i make it so that the user has to input their own username and password. and the sends the following http request https://SERVER-ADDRESS:PORT/site/login?
username=USER&password=PASS

Comment: String url = "https://SERVER-ADDRESS:PORT/site/login?username=" + user + "&password=" + password;

Comment: Just a little problem, params,DigitalReplicaConstant.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT); i have syntax error on tokens,delete these tokens

Comment: put it 1000 * 60 * 2 (2 mins)

Comment: instead of DigitalReplicaConstant.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT, updated my answer..

Comment: now the setConnectionTimeout has error "is not applicable for arguments (int)"

Comment: HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000 * 60 * 2);

Comment: httpClient.execute(httpget)
EntityUtils.toString(entity);
entity.consumeContent();

are all unhandled exception type ClientProtocolException

Comment: Hey Sorry, final question. How can i create an output to test if the connection was successful.

Comment: check the string returned from String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

Comment: How can i print the output?